# Parsing JSON response and rendering it in React

Tags: html, json, reactjs

I am trying to display json response in my react component

```
class JsonComponents extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      components: []
    };
  }



  _fetchComponents() {
   jQuery.ajax ({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos',
      success: (components) => {
        this.setState({components})
        console.log("Logging something ", this.state.components);
      }
    });


  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this._fetchComponents();
  }

  render() {

// HOw to parse JSON and render it in a table in JSX?
     return <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.components, null, 2) }</pre></div>;


  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<JsonComponents  />, 
  document.getElementById('container'));
```

HOw do I parse the returned json and render only a key from the response?

Comment: Sample structure of the returned json would help.

Comment: You don't need to parse data from AJAX call. You can already use it from this.state.components like this: [http://jsbin.com/futaziq/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/futaziq/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thank you!!! That was what I was looking for :)

Comment: ALTHOUGH IT IS NOW GIVING ME AN ERROR Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop